# Decrease space between staves in Gregorio

Tags: gregorio

How can I reduce the spacing between staves? I decreased my staff size using `\grechangestaffsize{8}` and decreased the font size using `\tiny`, but the space between the staves did not decrease appropriately, as you can see in the screenshot below. I would like to eliminate this extra space.

[image]

Code to reproduce:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[autocompile]{gregoriotex}

\begin{document}
\grechangestaffsize{8}
{\tiny
\baselineskip=0pt
\gregorioscore{test}}

\end{document}
```

And the gabc (not identical to what I used above, but will give a comparable result):

```
mode: 4;
%%
(c4) (e+) 1. Læ(hg)tá(gh)tus(h) sum(h) in(h) his,(h) quæ(h) dic(hg)ta(gi) sunt(i) mi(hi)hi:(h.) *(:) In(hg) do(gh)mum(h) Dó(h)mi(h)ni(gf) í(gh)bi(g)mus.(e.) (::) <i>Ant.</i>() (e+Z)
(e+) (::) 2. Stan(hg~)tes(gh) e(h)rant(hg) pe(gi)des(i) nos(hi)tri,(h.) *(:) in(hg) á(gh)tri(h)is(h) tu(h)is,(h) Je(gf)rú(gh)sa(g)lem.(e.) (::) <i>Ant.</i>() (e+Z)
(e+) 3. Qui(hg)a(gh) il(h)lic(h) se(h)dé(h)runt(h) se(h)des(hg) in(gi) ju(i)dí(hi)ci(h)o,(h.) *(:) se(hg)des(gh) su(h)per(h) do(gf)mum(gh) Da(g)vid.(e.) (::) <i>Ant.</i>() (e+Z)
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Could you include some code that reproduces that image please? It is difficult to help without knowing your `\documentclass`, packages and custom macros

Comment: I added some code that produces a similar result. Thanks for suggesting that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the baselineskip in Gregorio with `\grechangedim` like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[autocompile]{gregoriotex}

\begin{document}
\grechangestaffsize{8}
\grechangedim{baselineskip}{20pt plus 2pt minus 2pt}{fixed}
{\tiny
\gregorioscore{test}}

\end{document}
```

And this is how it looks for me:

[image]